# How to exclude annotation element if other is set

Tags: java, annotations

If I have annotation like this:

```
public @interface MyAnnotaton{

   String className():

   Class clazz();

}
```

what i should do to limit setting element className if element clazz is set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide a default value for one of the elements, and in your AnnotationProcessor code the necessary logic to detect which element should be processed

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
   Class clazz();
   String className() default "<none>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd wager to say this is impossible – annotations aren't executable code and do not intrinsically have *any* logic. Either settle on one of the two, or pick which one takes precedence and document the annotation accordingly.